# Why am i receiving RPC server is unavailable error when looping?

Tags: powershell, rpc

I have a Powershell script to find specific servers and their corresponding service accounts. If I modify the script to use a single server and a single service account, the results are what I expect. If I loop thru the servers and accounts, I receive the following error:

```
#################################################################
# Find Service Account(s) used to start Services on a Server(s) #
#################################################################

$accounts = (Get-Content C:\Users\location\Scripts\Service_Accounts.txt)

Remove-Item -path C:\Users\location\Scripts\ServiceAccountFnd.txt -force -erroraction silentlycontinue

Import-Module ActiveDirectory  # Imports the Active Directory PowerShell module #

## Retrieves servers in the domain based on the search criteria ##

$servers=Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "namehere*"} -property *

## For Each Server, find the services running under the user specified in $account ##
ForEach ($server in $servers) {
   Write-Host $server
   ForEach ($account in $accounts) {
      Write-Host $account
      Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $server | Where-Object {$_.StartName -like "*$account*"} | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -property @{n='ServerName';e={$_.__SERVER}}, StartName, Name -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\location\Scripts\ServiceAccountFnd.txt -append -Width 150
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the systems you're contacting are even online?  Most of the time with scripts like this I use `Test-Connection` to verify the servers are even responding before attempting a WMI query.

Comment: I am not 100% certain, maybe 99.9% certain :-) but will use your suggestion to test the connection. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. You can try to replace this `$servers=Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "namehere*"} -property *` to this `$servers=Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "namehere*"} -property * | select name` like vrdse says in answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `$server` variable does not only contain the hostname, but also all attributes of the AD computer object.

Try to change the `ComputerName` value to `$server.name`.

If that doesn't help: Can you confirm, that you used the very same computer in the loop as without the loop, as you described? I'd assume that you try to access another computer, which is not configured as expected.

Besided that, I'd recommend you to use `Get-CimInstance` rather than `Get-WmiObject`, as it doesn't use RPC, but WinRM by default. WinRM is more firewall friendly, secure and faster.